# Solve the initial value problem, heat equation. What method to use.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve the initial value problem:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> u_t = k u_{xx} \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty, 0\leq t < \infty\\
> u(x,0) = \phi(x) \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty
> \end{cases}$$
>   where $\phi(x) = e^{-x}$ for $x > 0$ and $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x\leq 0$.

I know we can use the Fourier transform to solve this but I am wondering if that is the easiest way of doing so. Any suggestions on how to solve this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel . The fundamental solution is given by $u(x,t) = \int \phi(y) \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}}{\rm d}y$. Fourier transforms is [one way](http://www.andrewcheong.com/a/andrewcheong.heat-equation.pdf) of deriving it. [Here](http://www.soarcorp.com/research/Heat_Kernel_1D.pdf) is another one.

Comment: @Winther Must we derive the fundamental solution before using it to solve the problem for it to be considered a complete solution or can we just use the fundamental solution and go from there?

Comment: It depends on the context. If you are taking a PDE course then this solution is usually thought and derived in class and then you can use it when you need it without deriving it (unless the problem explicitly asks you to derive it). If you haven't seen it before then it's a good idea to try to do the derivation yourself.